# BA (Baskerville) Math Font from micropress available?

Tags: font-recommendation, latex, mathematics

For several years now, I've been trying to get my hands on the BA Math Font from [micropress](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/bamath/bamain.htm).  But I can't find anyone who has it, or who is willing to sell it to me (including the original authors).  And the online ordering form at the referenced website doesn't do anything -- I've tried it.  As far as I can tell, this font has disappeared from the face of the planet! :)

Does anyone know where I can buy this font?  Anyone have any information that might help me to track this down?

Comment: Downvoted because the link you provided clearly has an order form page marked.

Comment: @Ryan the order form is unsecured, thus it is not advisable even to try to buy anything there.

Comment: ftp://ftp.micropress-inc.com/CTAN/fonts/

Comment: @Ryan As I stated, the order form doesn't work.  I tried it -- even though it's unsecured.

Comment: @SaturnsEye Thanks, but those are the Times New Roman and Helvetica based fonts.  Not the Baskerville ones.

Comment: Ah missed that. I've removed my downvote. Did you call them? The last update on their website is 2005, they might no longer be in business.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks.  Yeah, called, emailed, smoke signals... everything I can think of.  Yet, nothing :(

Comment: Unfortunately, people have been trying to contact these folks to buy the fonts for years now --- not sure why they keep the web pages up.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I am trying to find a copy of the Informal Maths font they used to offer.

Comment: No I never had any luck.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I did some digging and it sounds like the company is in fact out of business.

Here are a few alternatives people have suggested:

- http://www.gaehrken.de/tex/
- http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/utopia/
- http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/utopia-md/

If those won't work the only thing it appears might get the original Baskerville Math Font is contacting [Michael Vulis](http://www.ccny.cuny.edu/profiles/Michael-Vulis.cfm), Associate Professor at CUNY. It is my understanding he either worked for, or was the founder of, Micropress. I didn't see any info as to whether Professor Vulis was receptive to such requests but you can certainly try.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have tried to contact Michael Vulis, but haven't been successful.